# Is there a way to animate autolayout constraints using an autolayout extension programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout

- I am creating this app entirely programmatically

I want to animate the the addButton from the bottom right corner to the centerYAnchor of the headerLabel, preferably using this autolayout extension (extensions below).

```
view.addSubview(headerLabel)
    headerLabel.setAnchors(top: view.topAnchor, paddingTop: 50, bottom: nil, paddingBottom: 0, left: view.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 40, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 40, centerX: nil, centerY: nil, width: 0, height: 0)

view.addSubview(addButton)
    addButton.setAnchors(top: nil, paddingTop: 0, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, paddingBottom: 16, left: nil, paddingLeft: 0, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 16, centerX: nil, centerY: nil, width: 60.0, height: 60.0)
```

When the user clicks the button, I want the button's centerYAnchor to animate upwards and match the centerYAnchor of the headerLabel.

```
@objc func addListButtonClicked(sender : UIButton){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {


    })
}
```

Can anyone help me with this or give me some direction on where to start?Thanks!

Comment: Swap out constraints as desired and animate `layoutIfNeeded`.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown your `.setAnchors` extension, so... Is it simply adding constraints? Is it tracking constraints and changing them?

Comment: Basic technique shown here https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p183animationAndAutolayout3/AnimateAutolayoutTest/ViewController.swift

Comment: @DonMag it's just adding constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

Use "start" and "end" constraint vars for your `addButton`, then activate / deactivate them based on where you want the button.

```
var startConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var endConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(addButton)

    // set ONLY right anchor, width and height
    addButton.setAnchors(top: nil, paddingTop: 0, bottom: nil, paddingBottom: 0, left: nil, paddingLeft: 0, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 16, centerX: nil, centerY: nil, width: 60.0, height: 60.0)

    // define "starting location" constraint
    // bottom of addButton 16-pts from bottom of view
    startConstraint = addButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0)

    // define "ending location" constraint
    // centerY of addButton at centerY of headerLabel
    endConstraint = addButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerLabel.centerYAnchor)

    // activate the starting constraint
    startConstraint.isActive = true

}
```

Then, when you want to animate the button up to the headerView:

```
@objc func addListButtonClicked(sender : UIButton) {

    // deactivate the start constraint      
    startConstraint.isActive = false

    // activate the end constraint 
    endConstraint.isActive = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

}
```

This would also allow you to animate the button back to its original position by reversing the order and activated states:

```
    // moves button from bottom up to header view
    startConstraint.isActive = false
    endConstraint.isActive = true

    // moves button from header view down to bottom
    endConstraint.isActive = false
    startConstraint.isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
// remove old bottom constraint 
self.view.constraints.forEach {
   if $0.firstItem == self.addButton && $0.firstAttribute == .bottom  {
       self.view.removeConstraint($0)
   }
} 

// add a new centerY
self.addButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.headerLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true 

  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: { 
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  })
```

---

You can  also do ( not recommended to mix autolayout with frame)

```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: { 
      self.addButton.center = self.headerLabel.center
  })
```